# Return an error message when something goes wrong in the API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to return an error message when something goes wrong in the API, I have already done this for all requests from the API, but for a specific error, the action that shows all users that is `IEnumerable`.

**.../API/Controllers/UserControllers:**

```
...

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<User> GetAll()
    {
        try
        {
            return userRepository.GetAll();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500,ex.InnerException.Message);
        }

    }

...
```

My `return StatusCode(500,ex.InnerException.Message);` show this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

How can I solve this?

Comment: For a better design I suggest to not try-catch in your controllers. Rather have the business logic return a proper error if this is a scenario that you foresee and therefore is not *exception*al. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

Comment: Brandon, the [tag:API] tag is marked "DO NOT USE".  Please read the tags before applying them, and when someone fixes it for you, don't undo it without a good reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your method to return IActionResult. ControllerBase contains lots of helper methods for returning different types of result, include Ok (when the request was processed successfully, HTTP status code 200), BadRequest (HTTP status code 400), NotFound (HTTP status code 404) etc. For HTTP status code 500 there is no dedicated helper method, but there is a generic StatusCode helper method which you can use for any other status code:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult<IEnumerable<User>> GetAll()
{
    try
    {
        return Ok(userRepository.GetAll());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, ex.InnerException.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should make your controller return `IActionResult` instead of an `IEnumerable<User>` and `return Ok(userRepository.GetAll())` instead of just `userRepository.GetAll()`.